# MySql Substring Index, Find and replace characters

Tags: mysql, replace, substring

I need to find the first and second "_" and extract whatever is between.
example data

```
doc_856_abc_123
doc_876_xyz_999
```

So far I have the following substring query.  But I need help

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX( column, '_', 2 )
```

It is outputting

```
doc_856
doc_867
```

How do I combine the above query to maybe another substring go get the desired results.  Which would be.

```
856
867
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just apply SUBSTRING_INDEX again on the resulted string

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '_', 2 ), '_', -1)
```